# how to parse this response using JSONObject

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have this response that I get back form server. I want to parse it and get the hospital_name out of it. How would I go about it?

```
[
    {
        "Hospital": {
            "id": "63083",
            "hospital_name": "Colorado Mental Health Inst",
            "hospital_add_1": "1600 W 24th St",
            "hospital_add_2": null,
            "hospital_city": "Pueblo",
            "hospital_state": "CO",
            "hospital_zip": "81003",
            "hospital_phone": "719-546-4000\r",
            "hospital_fax": null,
            "hospital_description": null,
            "callcenter_agent_approval": "0",
            "hospital_site": "",
            "mdpocket_approval": "0",
            "facebook": ""
        },
        "Floor": [],
        "Department": [],
        "Image": [],
        "Notes": []
    },
    {
        "Hospital": {
            "id": "63084",
            "hospital_name": "Parkview Medical Center",
            "hospital_add_1": "400 W 16th St",
            "hospital_add_2": null,
            "hospital_city": "Pueblo",
            "hospital_state": "CO",
            "hospital_zip": "81003",
            "hospital_phone": "719-584-4000\r",
            "hospital_fax": null,
            "hospital_description": null,
            "callcenter_agent_approval": "0",
            "hospital_site": "",
            "mdpocket_approval": "0",
            "facebook": ""
        },
        "Floor": [],
        "Department": [],
        "Image": [],
        "Notes": []
    },
    {
        "Hospital": {
            "id": "63085",
            "hospital_name": "St Mary-Corwin Medical Center",
            "hospital_add_1": "1008 Minnequa Ave",
            "hospital_add_2": null,
            "hospital_city": "Pueblo",
            "hospital_state": "CO",
            "hospital_zip": "81004",
            "hospital_phone": "719-560-4000\r",
            "hospital_fax": null,
            "hospital_description": null,
            "callcenter_agent_approval": "0",
            "hospital_site": "",
            "mdpocket_approval": "0",
            "facebook": ""
        },
        "Floor": [],
        "Department": [],
        "Image": [],
        "Notes": []
    }
]
```

**EDITED THE JSON**
**UPDATED JSON **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ // json array node 
{  // json object node 
"Hospital": { // json object Hospital
```

To parse

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("jsonstring");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.getJSONObject(i);
   JSONObject jb1 =(JSONObject) jb.getJSONObject("Hospital");
   String name =  jb1.getString("hospital_name");
   Log.i("name....",name);
}
```

Log

```
02-18 03:09:43.950: I/name....(951): Colorado Mental Health Inst
02-18 03:09:43.950: I/name....(951): Parkview Medical Center
02-18 03:09:43.950: I/name....(951): St Mary-Corwin Medical Center
```

Comment: gives error here JSONObject jb = jr.getJSONObject(i); 
The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: @Autolycus check whether its a valid json @ jsonlint.com

Comment: JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(responseData);
     //JSONArray jr = jsonResponse.get
     for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
     {
        JSONObject jb = jr.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject jb1 = jb.getJSONObject("Hospital");
        String name =  jb1.getString("hospital_name");
        Log.v(TAG, name);
     }

and that code throws json exception

Comment: @Autolycus update it in your post editing the question

Comment: the answer from Hariharan Tamilan. But you were very close as well.

Comment: @Autolycus my answer is no different from his if you read my answer carefully

Comment: you are right. You deserver the accepted answer as you were the one with this first.

Answer (score 2):

You won't-  its invalid JSON.  You're missing most of your "" around field names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
JSONArray tot_array = new JSONArray(response);

for(int i = 0; i< tot_array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject obj = tot_array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject hospital_obj = obj.getJSONObject("Hospital");
    String hospital_name =  hospital_obj.getString("hospital_name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the fastjson (https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this cool libray for parsing JSOn in Android its called GSON https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ . Via this parsing this very simple.

Comment: I know its not the direct answer , but just checkout this lib u will get directly get list of Hospitals as output.

Comment: I am following a tutorial so I want to stay on the track and use what they are using. thanks

Comment: okies .... everytime looping ur json is painful and is more prone to error .. just check this out .. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not a valid JSON object. Check out [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) before trying to parse a string as JSON. After which, you can read about [parsing JSON in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_JSON_Parser_Example). It's easy enough with the built-in `org.json`, but should be much easier if you use one of the many Java libraries out there that simplifies it further. You can look into [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), two of the most capable utilities for your purpose.