# JSONObject giving me errors

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a json returning back to me from server. I am trying to iterate over it but its gving me error on this line

```
 JSONObject obj = jsonHospitals.getJSONObject(i);
```

The error underlines in red .getJSONObject(i) and gives me two options
1- change to optJSONObject(...)
2- change type of 'i' to 'String'

What can I do to use JSONObject and iterate over the json. I am new to android so please bear with me fellas!
Below is some more of the code

```
String responseData = new String(charArray);

                    JSONObject jsonHospitals = new JSONObject(responseData);

                    for(int i = 0; i< jsonHospitals.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject obj = jsonHospitals.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject hospital_obj = obj.getJSONObject("Hospital");
                        String hospital_name =  hospital_obj.getString("hospital_name");
                        Log.v(TAG, hospital_name);
                    }
```

Thanks
**UPDATE**
**OK TRIED SOMETHING NEW AND ALL POSTED HERE NOW**

I tried this code

```
try {

                URL hospitalFeedUrl = new URL("siteresponseaddress");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)hospitalFeedUrl.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    int contentLenght = connection.getContentLength();
                    char[] charArray = new char[contentLenght];
                    reader.read(charArray);
                    String responseData = new String(charArray);

                    JSONArray jsonHospitals = new JSONArray(responseData);

                    for(int i = 0; i< jsonHospitals.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject obj = jsonHospitals.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject hospital_obj = obj.getJSONObject("Hospital");
                        String hospital_name =  hospital_obj.getString("hospital_name");
                        Log.v(TAG, hospital_name);
                    }
                    Log.v(TAG, responseData);
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unsccessful HHTP Response Code "+ responseCode);
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Code " + responseCode);
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "exception caught: ", e);    
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "exception IO caught: ", e); 
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "General exception", e);
            }
```

NOW thats giving me the following in LOG CAT

```
02-21 03:13:08.350: D/dalvikvm(838): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 5% free 2949K/3072K, paused 153ms, total 154ms
02-21 03:13:08.350: I/dalvikvm-heap(838): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-21 03:13:08.460: D/dalvikvm(838): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3567K/3696K, paused 101ms, total 101ms
02-21 03:13:09.310: I/Choreographer(838): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-21 03:13:09.460: D/gralloc_goldfish(838): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-21 03:13:15.110: D/dalvikvm(838): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 188K, 7% free 3892K/4156K, paused 171ms, total 208ms
02-21 03:13:15.350: D/dalvikvm(838): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 375K, 13% free 3898K/4464K, paused 60ms, total 79ms
02-21 03:13:15.350: E/MainListActivity(838): General exception
02-21 03:13:15.350: E/MainListActivity(838): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 21961 of [{"Hospital":{"id":"61790","hospital_name":"Goodland Regional Medical Ctr","hospital_add_1":"220 W 2nd St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Goodland","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67735","hospital_phone":"785-890-3625\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61795","hospital_name":"Cheyenne County Hospital","hospital_add_1":"210 W 1st St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Saint Francis","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67756","hospital_phone":"785-332-2104\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61801","hospital_name":"Stanton County Hospital","hospital_add_1":"404 N Chestnut St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Johnson","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67855","hospital_phone":"620-492-6250\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61802","hospital_name":"Kearny County Hospital","hospital_add_1":"500 E Thorpe St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Lakin","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67860","hospital_phone":"620-355-7111\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61803","hospital_name":"Wichita County Health Center","hospital_add_1":"211 E Earl St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Leoti","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67861","hospital_phone":"620-375-2233\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61808","hospital_name":"Hamilton County Hospital","hospital_add_1":"700 N Huser St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Syracuse","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67878","hospital_phone":"620-384-7461\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61809","hospital_name":"Greeley County Health Services","hospital_add_1":"506 3rd St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Tribune","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67879","hospital_phone":"620-376-4221\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61810","hospital_name":"Bob Wilson Memorial Hospital","hospital_add_1":"415 N Main St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Ulysses","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67880","hospital_phone":"620-356-1266\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61812","hospital_name":"Morton County Hospital","hospital_add_1":"445 Hilltop St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Elkhart","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67950","hospital_phone":"620-697-2141\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"61813","hospital_name":"Stevens County Hospital","hospital_add_1":"1006 S Jackson St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Hugoton","hospital_state":"KS","hospital_zip":"67951",
```

// CATLOG FINISHED

//this is not part of CATLOG
**JSON**

```
[{"Hospital":{"id":"63083","hospital_name":"Colorado Mental Health Inst","hospital_add_1":"1600 W 24th St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Pueblo","hospital_state":"CO","hospital_zip":"81003","hospital_phone":"719-546-4000\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"63084","hospital_name":"Parkview Medical Center","hospital_add_1":"400 W 16th St","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Pueblo","hospital_state":"CO","hospital_zip":"81003","hospital_phone":"719-584-4000\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]},{"Hospital":{"id":"63085","hospital_name":"St Mary-Corwin Medical Center","hospital_add_1":"1008 Minnequa Ave","hospital_add_2":null,"hospital_city":"Pueblo","hospital_state":"CO","hospital_zip":"81004","hospital_phone":"719-560-4000\r","hospital_fax":null,"hospital_description":null,"callcenter_agent_approval":"0","hospital_site":"","mdpocket_approval":"0","facebook":""},"Floor":[],"Department":[],"Image":[],"Notes":[]}]
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the JSON you are trying to parse. Its unclear if you actually have a JSON array or an object.

Comment: @BrianRoach i guess its linked to his previous question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846806/how-to-parse-this-response-using-jsonobject

Comment: And, the answer there tells the op *exactly* how to parse it.

Comment: I am seeing catlog complaining on parsing

Comment: @Autolycus this seems to be invalid json. pls check once @ jsonlint.com

Comment: You have invalid json. Mystery solved.

Comment: Json is 100% valid as I checked it already on multiple json validation sites

Comment: please have a look at json added

Comment: Your computer disagrees, and is telling you that in that error. Of course, since what you're doing in your code isn't how to read the response from a http query thats not surprising; you aren't reading the entire response and then are passing the incomplete json to the parser.

Comment: ok then can you tell me what is the fix? @Brian Roach

Comment: @Autolycus what is this `String responseData = new String(charArray);` what is `charArray`?. How do you get the json?

Comment: Duplicate of: [how to parse json in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) the first answer covers getting data via http and everything else you could possibly need to know

Comment: Brian Roach, if the answer worked in mentioned post, by the way also by me, I wouldnt be asking again. @Raghunandan, the responseData is the actual json that I posted above.

Comment: @Autolycus post the code of how you get your json.

Comment: @Raghunandan its already posted. Please look in try block. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getJSONObject` which takes int as a param.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
public JSONObject getJSONObject (String name)

Added in API level 1
Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject.

Throws
JSONException   if the mapping doesn't exist or is not a JSONObject.
```

Hence the error. You need to post your json for further help

Your json seems similar to the one in your previous question for which i have already answered @

[how to parse this response using JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846806/how-to-parse-this-response-using-jsonobject)

Edit:

```
    try
    {
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
     HttpGet request = new HttpGet("your url ");  
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
     HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
     String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 
         JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(_response);
         for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
         {
         JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.getJSONObject(i);
         JSONObject jb1 =(JSONObject) jb.getJSONObject("Hospital");
         String name =  jb1.getString("hospital_name");
         Log.i("name....",name);
         }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: @BrianRoach maybe. not here http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String).

Comment: please see my updat. I have added a detailed information as to what CatLog is saying etc

Comment: @Autolycus can you post the url so that we can see the full json?

Comment: I will try to copy paste the full json in the question. It is a internal site so the outsiders dont have access to it. Give me 5 minutes

Comment: @Autolycus your json looks exactly like the one in your previos question. So that answer should work for you. you have the error coz you are not reading the full json.

Comment: no that answer is giving the stack error that I told you already. Please dont refer to that question any more as I am having stack errors that I posted above. thanks

Comment: @Autolycus that is the way to parse the json. its right. the error is not bcoz of the code posted there

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
JSONObject obj = jsonHospitals.getJSONObject(i);
```

to:

```
JSONObject obj = jsonHospitals.getJSONObject(String.valueof(i));
```

The reason is because the the function getJSONObject expects a String as its Parameter - [Link to API Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate a JSONArray
Change this line:

> JSONObject jsonHospitals = new JSONObject(responseData);

to this

> JSONAray jsonHospitals = new JSONAray(responseData);

If it still doesn't work, could you provide your JSON resopnse.

Answer (score 0):

If your input json is of type JSON-array, you should treat it as such (see [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseData);
```

And then you can iterate over it, using:

```
for(int i = 0; i< array.length(); i++) {
  array.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Hi Autolycus,
             I think you have to parse  responseData as JSONArray like below

            **JSONArray jsonHospitals = new JSONArray(responseData);**

          for(int i = 0; i< jsonHospitals.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject obj = jsonHospitals.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject hospital_obj = obj.getJSONObject("Hospital");
                    String hospital_name =  hospital_obj.getString("hospital_name");
                    Log.v(TAG, hospital_name);
                }

       Hope it will work for you :)
```